# $scope.on in angularjs and binding it with an event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.$on('properties:update', function (event, properties) {
        $scope.properties = properties;
        console.log('fired');
});
```

What does the above code does? I did not see any `update` method elsewhere in the controller and in the view. Above event only trigger once upon entering the page. How to trigger it programmatically?

Comment: search for `properties:update` in the project, there's got to be somewhere a code like this `$scope.$broadcast('properties:update'` or `$scope.$emit('properties:update'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is used for communicating between controllers.
Like two controllers in one application can communicate with each other through broadcast and on handlers. See the below example.

**The event broadcaster a different controller**

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('showMenu', $scope.ticket_items);
```

**The event reciever is as follows**

```
$scope.$on("showMenu",function(event,ticket_items){
    $scope.ticketVisible = false;
    $scope.ticket_items = ticket_items;
});
```

Comment: why u need $rooteScope when u do $broadcast? I thought u can arldy share variable using $rootScope?

Comment: When you broadcast you should use $rootScope not $scope. It should come with controller like this.

Comment: App.controller('YourCtrl', 
        function($scope,$rootScope) {